# Could not find rake with bundle exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

When I try execute '*bundle exec rake anything*', I get error:

```
Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But when I execute simple *'rake anything'*, rake is working.

Of cause, I tried setup gem any way, which I know:

- gem install rake -v=10.1.0
- Wrote "*gem 'rake', '10.1.0'*" in Gemfile, then execute *bundle install*
- I installed gem for all rvm: *rvm all do gem install rake -v 10.1.0*

This situation really frustration, because simple *rake* works, but with *bundle exec* doesn't want.

I need execute rake with *bundle exec*

Really need your help!

Comment: What is output when you type `rvm list` on the command line?  Which is your default ruby?

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: ruby-2.0.0-p247 - current && default

Comment: i ran `bundle install`

Comment: what happens when you type `ruby-2.0.0-p247 -S gem list` and `ruby-2.0.0-p247 -S bundle exec gem list` ?

Comment: executing `ruby-2.0.0-p247 -S gem list` gives list of gems.
when i type `ruby-2.0.0-p247 -S bundle exec gem list`, it writes again `Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources.
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue, with exactly the same error message, with the same Ruby version yesterday. I solved it by removing this line from `.bundle/config` in my repository:

```
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

Comment: where is .bundle/config?

Comment: Not sure for you, mine was in the Rails project root directory. I guess it depends on the specific configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and my solution was:
Delete my gemfile.lock

```
rm Gemfile.lock
```

donwgrade rake in my gemfile

```
gem 'rake', '10.0.2'
```

finally

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem with an AWS instance, managed by OpsWorks.  I was logged in as ec2user.  I switched over to the deploy user via `sudo su - deploy` and ran the bundle command again and it completed without error

Answer (score -1):

I got a similar error when I tried running 'bundle exec $EXECUTABLE' without running 'bundle install' first :|